# PC only starts up after about 5 reboots

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

I built a computer 3 months ago, and there were no problems with it until it got cool at home (or at least I think the problem is the low temperature of about 17-19 degrees celsius).

What's going on: As soon as I try to turn on the computer in the morning, I see the normal initialization of the motherboard (ASRock logo), Windows booting, but then something clicks in the computer (sounds like a power supply, but again guesses) and the computer just turns off and tries to turn on again. This happens 5 times in a row, and everything turns on as it should be.

This does not happen if I restart the computer after 2-3 hours of work. It just turns on the first time.

PC:

- ASRock B760 Pro RS/D4 motherboard
- DeepCool DQ750 power supply
- GPU MSI Geforce RTX 3060
- Intel i5-10400f
- RAM Patriot Signature Line Premium [PSP432G3200KH1]

Comment: “17-19 degrees” is that Fahrenheit or Centigrade? I assume it’s Fahrenheit.

Comment: celsius, I'm sorry that I didn't specify

Comment: So that would be about 62-66 degrees Fahrenheit. That doesn’t seem that cold? That actually seems nominal if you ask me. I agree, it is most likely a power supply issue. But 62-66F seems utterly fine to me.

Comment: I suggest that try to run the system outside of the cabinet with minimal components and see if the issue persists or not. To turn on the PC outside of the cabinet momentarily short the 2 Power Pins on the motherboard by a metallic object like a screw driver. Remove extra drives if any from PC. If PSU has a power off button, try to turn it off from the PSU button and check again. It seems during initial phase some protection in PSU might be kicking in like a short circuit or overvoltage or current, just a guess.

Comment: Have you changed BIOS settings to proper ones? CPU and RAM needs proper frequency and timings.

Comment: Standard question - did you bother to take any kind of proper esd precautions when you built it? Occasionally & momentarily touching metal does not count.

Comment: @pbies I didn't change anything in the bios, because I think it's better not to touch anything than to touch something I don't understand

Comment: @Bib no esd protection, but the problem arose only after 3 months, and not immediately

Comment: @disssbalance You need to change frequencies and timings to proper for the hardware in BIOS to make computer even run.

Comment: @pbies I am as honest as possible, I personally built the computer myself, and I can assure you that I did not change anything in the bios

Comment: @disssbalance I understand. And I know that you need to do that.

Comment: It does not matter if it only arose after 3 months. It is possible it started 3 month ago, got worse, until today. Learn from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0lsHDU2Sr4

Answer (score -2):

Regarding your issue, it sounds like your PC might be experiencing a power supply or motherboard problem, particularly when it's cold. The clicking sound and the need for multiple reboots suggest a component isn't initializing correctly on the first try.

A few things you might want to check:

1. **Power Supply**: The DeepCool DQ750 is generally reliable, but it might be struggling in the cold. Power supplies can be less efficient in lower temperatures. If possible, test with another PSU.
2. **Motherboard**: Cold temperatures can sometimes cause contraction in solder or other materials, leading to poor connections. Check if there's any visible issue on the ASRock B760 Pro RS/D4 motherboard.
3. **Thermal Expansion/Contraction**: Components expand and contract with temperature changes. This could be causing issues with connections, especially if they're not super tight.
4. **Capacitors**: They can behave differently in the cold. If a capacitor is failing, it might not work correctly until it warms up a bit.
5. **BIOS Update**: Ensure your motherboard's BIOS is up to date. Manufacturers often release updates that improve stability and compatibility.
6. **Electrical Interference**: Rare, but cold weather can sometimes increase static or other interferences. Check if your grounding is proper.

Try to keep your room a bit warmer and see if the issue persists. If it does, you might want to consult a professional or consider warranty options.

Comment: But the temperature we’re talking about are not even that cold.

Comment: Yeah. What @Ramhound said. 17-19 degrees Celsius is 62-66 degrees Fahrenheit. That is not that cold at all and honestly seems like a nominal temperature range.